# How does iMediaShare work android

Tags: android

I installed this application called [iMediaShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bianor.ams&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmJpYW5vci5hbXMiXQ..) which helps stream youtube videos on my tv. What I want to know is where would I find the protocol information or sample code where I can transmit an image/video file to my samsung tv. There must be some documentaion of some sort or some cookbook which would help me get started. Has anyone worked on something like this before. If so how exactly is the upnp protocol stream sent from android ?